# MSBuild and VisualStudio build difference

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am having a perplexing issue building our solution in VisualStudio.  I have turned on detailed logging and tracked the issue to the following.  When I build the solution in Visual Studio (2022 17.8.7) by just going to the Build menu and invoking Build Solution, the project in question publishes this in the logs:

```
88>Done building target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" in project "WindowsTouchApp.csproj". 
88>Target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways" skipped, due to false condition; ( '@(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectoryAlways)' != '' ) was evaluated as ( '' != '' ). 
88>Target "_CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory" in file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\arm64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\Users\hf\LocalProjects\Repositories\replay\Dev\Src\Framework\WindowsTouchApp\WindowsTouchApp.csproj" (target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" depends on it): 
88>Done building target "_CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory" in project "WindowsTouchApp.csproj".
```

Meanwhile when I execute an MSBuild command from command prompt (as our build / Jenkins server does):

```
msbuild Dev\src\Client.sln /nr:false /target:Build  /p:nowarn="1607,1591,1573" /p:WarningLevel=0 /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x64" /fl /v:detailed
```

The same area of the log shows:

```
Done building target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" in project "WindowsTouchApp.csproj".
Target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways" in file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\arm64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "c:\Users\hf\LocalProjects\Repositories\replay\Dev\src\Framework\WindowsTouchApp\WindowsTouchApp.csproj" (target "_CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory" depends on it):
Task "Copy"
  Creating directory "..\..\..\Bin\15dd936825ad475ea34e35f3f54217a6".
  Creating directory "..\..\..\Bin\15dd936825ad475ea34e35f3f54217a6".
  ...
  Done building target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways" in project "WindowsTouchApp.csproj".
Target "_CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory" in file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\arm64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "c:\Users\hf\LocalProjects\Repositories\replay\Dev\src\Framework\WindowsTouchApp\WindowsTouchApp.csproj" (target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" depends on it):
Done building target "_CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory" in project "WindowsTouchApp.csproj".
```

As you can see the VisualStudio build skips _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways but the MSBuild does not because their conditions are different somehow. And that's my dilemma. Why is VisualStudio skipping the _CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways - because SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectoryAlways is blank - and MSBuild is not.  Btw, the VisualStudio build result is what I want.  And just as additional data point, the items being copied during MSBuild are from a nuget package not referenced in the project in question.  The nuget package is referenced in another project in the solution.

Thank you for any help.

Update: I found a workaround for me as I could not figure out why the difference in builds when building the same solution seemingly.  I looked at the Solution Project Dependencies and removed the dependency of the project in question from the main EXE project of the solution (WindowsTouchApp).  This changed the MSBuild behavior where it no longer copies the dependent project nugets to the output of the main EXE project (WindowsTouchApp).

Comment: you have not found something really new. It is a well know that MSBUILD is more restrictive and requires following certain rules where VS build is more forgiving and can do things for you. For example MS build would require you to add explicit package restore while VS "knows" to do that. And there are many other conditions like that.